# OrbFeaturesFinder giving different result when implemented on Android platform

Tags: opencv, android, opencv3.1

I am using OrbFeaturesFinder to detect keypoints in Images.

```
Ptr<FeaturesFinder> finder;
finder = makePtr<OrbFeaturesFinder>();
vector<ImageFeatures> features(num_images);
(*finder)(img, features[i]);
```

I used this code on linux and implemented the same on android, but the results are different sometimes, as in given link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6byWY.jpg

What can be reason behind this nature of output.

method of accessing images in android
Image is saved in jpeg form, then read[edit] -

```
    for(int i = 0; i < imgNames.size(); i++){
        Bitmap bitmap = getThumbnail(imgNames.get(i));
        int imageW = bitmap.getWidth();
        int imageH = bitmap.getHeight();

        byte[] rgb = getByteArray(imageW, imageH, bitmap, "RGB");
        bitmap.recycle();

        Mat mRgb = new Mat(imageH, imageW, CvType.CV_8UC3);
        mRgb.put(0, 0, rgb);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgb, mRgb, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB, 3);

        panoImgs.add(mRgb);

    }
```

and sent to jni -

```
jclass matClass = env->FindClass("org/opencv/core/Mat");
jmethodID getNativeAddr = env->GetMethodID(matClass, "getNativeObjAddr", "()J");

int numImgs = env->GetArrayLength(jInputArray);

vector<Mat> natImgs;
for(int i=0; i < numImgs; ++i) {
    natImgs.push_back(
        *(Mat*)env->CallLongMethod(
                env->GetObjectArrayElement(jInputArray, i),
                getNativeAddr
        )
    );
}
```

for linux - I am saving the same image in jpeg format and then using imread to access files.

Comment: Don't save the images in a _lossy_ format like JPEG. Use a _lossless_ format like PNG.

Comment: I am reading the images, (as arraylist) in android after saving them in jpeg format. So input image for both linux and android is same.

Comment: You may still read the images slightly differently, since you may use different libs or versions to load jpeg files. Please try with PNG

Comment: Saving the image in png, takes time so I am avoiding that path.

Comment: i have edited and added the exact code for reading images in android. Have a look and tell me is it diff from imread

Comment: If input images are the same, you should check the ORB implementation source code between desktop (x86) and mobile (ARM?) platform: maybe on ARM hardware it uses some kind of optimizations (Neon intrinsics?) that will lead to slightly different result.

Comment: I checked the code, it uses gpu and opencl optimization. That is the reason for different outputs

Comment: I encountered such behavior between Linux (VMWare) and macOS (MacbookPro). The result is always better on macOS for the cases that bother me.